# How can I add one more property using c# into existing json object inside Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

Inside the `Azure function` my `input is ServiceBus queue properties`

Code is to retrieve that all properties are -

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{

 string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,jsonContent);
}
```

Output is -

```
[
    "{\"DeliveryCount\":\"1\",\MessageId\":\"bac52de2d23a487a9ed388f7313d93e5\"}"
]
```

I want to add one more property into this json object , how can I add it here in azure function so that I can return modified object like below -

```
[
    "{\"DeliveryCount\":\"1\",\MessageId\":\"bac52de2d23a487a9ed388f7313d93e5\",\"MyProperty\":\"TEST\"}"
]
```

Comment: serialise it to a type, add your property and deserialise again?

Comment: I dont have any type because i'm doing it into Azure Functions dynamically.

Comment: you could deserialise to `dynamic`. Doesn't have to be a concrete type.

Comment: not sure do you have working sample my code is bigger than shown into question. pls paste a working solution.

Comment: `dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonContent);` I would have thought. Then you can add a new property, and serialize it back again before returning it.

Comment: but what about new properties , how we can add it into same object at same time ?

Comment: `x.NewProperty = "y"`. That's the whole point about `dynamic`, it's, well...dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this quite easily, by de-serialising the JSON to an object, adding your new property and then serialising it back again. You don't even need a concrete type for this - `dynamic` should do the job for you.

For example:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonContent);
    obj.MyProperty = "TEST";
    string extendedJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, extendedJSON);
}
```